# Non-Animated scroll WKInterfaceTable to bottom

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am building a iMessage-type application for the apple watch and am trying to figure out a way to keep the table pinned to the bottom. I have been trying to write a 'scroll to bottom' method that looks like this to keep the table pinned to the bottom after inserting rows, but it is animated and I need something that is not animated. Is there any way to accomplish something like this on the apple watch?

```
- (void)scrollToBottom {
    NSUInteger count = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count - 1;
    [self.interfaceTable scrollToRowAtIndex:count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and research it is not possible with watchOS SDK 1. I don’t know about watchOS SDK 2.

A workaround would be to only load a few messages (about five of them), then scroll to bottom after the messages are displayed. If only a few messages are loaded and shown, the scroll is not too bothering.